# Jquery UI dialog and Close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I am using the following code for jquery dialog.

```
$("#div1").dialog({
            dialogClass: "county-dialog",
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            title: statecode,
            closeOnEscape: true,



        });


 .county-dialog
        {
            position: absolute !important;
            height: auto !important;
            top: 20% !important;
            left: 23% !important;
            display: block !important;
           width:auto !important;
           background: white !important;
        }
```

But when I close the dialog, the modal appearance is going but dialog is not closing.
If I am removing 'dialogClass' then it will hide dialog also. Please suggest a solution

Comment: Please include your county-dialog definition also in the question.

Comment: @Saritha S.R. share your html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ',' from last option in js. Plese remove !important from css containing:

```
display: block !important;
```